# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript

I should write a function that removes vowels from a string. I get an error message about null value. After several tries for fixing it, the message is this same, but I tried to filter null values.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at getCount at
>   Test.it at Test.describe at Object.exports.runInThisContext

```
function getCount(str) {
  var vowelsCount = 0;

  if (str && str.length){
    vowelsCount=str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;
  } else {
    vowelsCount=0;
  }

  return vowelsCount;
}

describe("Case 1", function(){
    it ("should be defined", function(){
        Test.assertEquals(getCount("abracadabra"), 5)
    });
});
```

Comment: Hint: what line it refers to.

Comment: 2nd hint: Actually two lines are possible

Comment: It refers to this line: Test.assertEquals(getCount("abracadabra"), 5)

Comment: What does `String.prototype.match` return if it matches nothing?

Comment: It returns null, but this test should filter: if (str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length != null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this ?

```
function getCount(str) {
  var vowelsCount = 0;

  if (str && str.length){
    var m = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi)
    if (m) return m.length;
  } else {
    vowelsCount=0;
  }

  return vowelsCount;
}

describe("Case 1", function(){
    it ("should be defined", function(){
        Test.assertEquals(getCount("abracadabra"), 5)
    });
});
```

Comment: Simple and great solution. Thanks a lot!